# Using Django with an existing database id field trouble

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, primary-key

I'm using Django with an existing database. I used **inspectdb** to create the models of the existing database. Everything works except for one important detail. It seems as though Django always assumes that there is an **id** field. For example, when I delete a field called **date** the run a migration, date is deleted from the table. However, when I try to delete the **id** field, it says **-Alter field id on table_name** even if there is no id field in the actual database table.

So, if you want make and use an id field in an existing database do you have to manually specify it in the model and database or is there a better way?

Comment: I believe Django does require an id field. Without it things like relationships between models will not be possible. Can you say a little more about why you are trying to work without an id field?

Answer (score 3):

By default Django creates an `id` field for your models even if you don't specify it, so, in this case, even if you delete the autogenerated:

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Django models will assume one exists, thus the message you see. This is because you *[need](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)* to have one primary key field.

So, yes, you have to specify your primary key by adding the `primary_key=True` attribute to the appropriate field on the model generated by `inspectdb`, or Django will assume your primary key is column `id`.

Keep in mind that, if you decide to add an `id` column to your table, you [shouldn't set it explicitly in your model](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter18.html):

> Each generated model has an attribute for every field, including id primary key fields. However, recall that Django automatically adds an id primary key field if a model doesn’t have a primary key. Thus, you’ll want to remove any lines that look like this:
>
> `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)`
>
> Not only are these lines redundant, but also they can cause problems if your application will be adding new records to these tables.

If you decide not to, make sure the column you end up choosing as PK doesn't have `NULL` nor repeated values.